# loops;end statement in python

Tags: python, loops

I have this assignment:
 - Write an error-trap condition loop that asks the user for username and password inputs iteratively, until correct values are entered.

- If username&password are correct end loop and print positive statement (“you entered the enchanted palace”).
- alternatively, prompt the user to re-enter username and password (“wrong username/password, try again”).
- If user tried and failed 3 times end loop and print a postponement statement (“wrong username/password, contact a system administrator”)

this is what I wrote so far:

```
while x in range(2):
    x = x + 1
    if  q1==username and q2==password:
       print("you entered the enchanted palace")
       break
    else:
       print("wrong username/password, try again")
       q1 = input("enter username: ")
       q2 = input("enter password: ")
```

I really don't know how to approach the third clause.

Answer (score 2):

You're so close:

1. Loop 3 times, rather than twice.
2. Replace the `while` and increment with `for x in range(3):`
3. Set a flag so you can tell whether or not you got a valid password.  If not, print that final message.

WIth a couple   of simple code updates ...

```
valid = False

for tries in range(3):
    if  q1==username and q2==password:
       print("you entered the enchanted palace")
       valid = True
       break
    else:
       print("wrong username/password, try again")
       q1 = input("enter username: ")
       q2 = input("enter password: ")

if not valid:
    print("wrong username/password, contact a system administrator”)
```